# Recommendations for converting inline JS containing different arguments into external script

Tags: javascript

I have some html with lines such as the following:

```
<ul>
<li onClick ="click(event, l1, url1)";>
..

<li onClick = "click(event, l2, url2)";>
..
```

etc.

If I take the onClick out I could iterate through the li elements and call attachEvent on each of them. But is there a simple way of dealing with the fact that the arguments differ for each event?

Comment: Assign IDs to them and then target them specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterating you should use delegation with something like jQuery's [on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  As far as passing different arguments, that entirely depends on what those arguments signify.  If they're contextual they could be retrieved from the DOM or otherwise you could utilize the elements [dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).